# Nested If Formula always returning FALSE - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to use a formula to tell if the cell value is within one of these ranges and set the value based on which is true.

If the value is between 0 and 10 set the cell value to "Needs Improvement"
If the value is between 10 and 15 set the cell value to "Meets Expectations"
If the value is greater than 15 Set the cell value to "Exceeds Expectations"

Any value I put it in always results in it being false meaning it doesn't apply any of those values.

My current formula is:

`=IF(AND(D21>=0, D21<=10), "Value is between 5 and 10", IF(AND(D21>=10, D21<=15), "Value is between 15 and 20", IF(AND(D21>=15, D21<=100), "Value is between 15 and 20", "Value is not within the specified range")))`

No matter what I change the number to it's always not within the specified range, I have tried googling so many things but I cannot figure it out

Comment: since every answer provided to you is not working, there must be something wrong with either your input, or your spreadsheet, try test the formula in a blank sheet, or share a dummie of your working sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. instead of `AND(D21>=0, D21<=10)`, use `ISBETWEEN(D21,0,10)`
2. the range of number you set is over lapping each other, correct way to go should be something like `AND(>=0,<=9)`, `AND(>=10,<=14)`, `AND(>=15,<=100)` in you case,
3. these kind of nested `IF()` is easy to get wrong if you don't know what you are doing. You can instead use a non-nested way to do what you want:

```
=LAMBDA(VALUE,
 IF(ISBETWEEN(VALUE,0,9),"Value is between 0 and 9","")
 &IF(ISBETWEEN(VALUE,10,14),"Value is between 10 and 14","")
 &IF(ISBETWEEN(VALUE,15,100),"Value is between 15 and 100","")
 &IF(OR(VALUE<0,VALUE>100),"Value is not within the specified range","")
)($D$21)
```

And since you are referencing `D21` instead of `D1` or `D2`,
make sure you have entered the value to test into cell `D21`.

Actually `IFS()` is a better option than `IF()` in this case:

```
=LAMBDA(VALUE,
 IFS(
  ISBETWEEN(VALUE,0,9),"Value is between 0 and 9",
  ISBETWEEN(VALUE,10,14),"Value is between 10 and 14",
  ISBETWEEN(VALUE,15,100),"Value is between 15 and 100",
  TRUE,"Value is not within the specified range"
 )
)($D$21)
```

Comment: I've tried the non-nested way you provided and it's still giving me "not within the specified range" regardless of the number I've put in D21

Comment: did you read my suggestion?
```And since you are referencing D21 instead of D1 or D2, make sure you have entered the value to test into cell D21.```

Comment: the formula is tested and work for sure, the only thing that can get wrong is your input, did you check if the value you are testing is really a number ?

Comment: It's possible I'm misunderstanding, but I did read your suggestion.
I copied the LAMBDA formula you provided, before I pasted it I set the cell value of D21 to 5 and it says it's not within the specified range.

Comment: what does it shows if you type in this formula: ```=D21``` and ```=ISNUMBER(D21)```?

Comment: `=D21` shows 5 but `=ISNUMBER(D21)` is saying false - not sure why..

Comment: than you are not giving the formula a number to test, that is the reason why none of the formulas work

Comment: I don't know how this would've changed but the cell format was set to "Plain Text" so I'm assuming that's why it wasn't reading it properly. Thank you for your help though, I was stuck on this for so long.

Answer (score 0):

use:

`=IF(AND(D21>=0, D21<=10), "Needs Improvement", IF(AND(D21>10, D21<=15), "Meets Expectations", IF(D21>15, "Exceeds Expectations")))`

Comment: I used this and it is always marking it as "Exceeds Expectations" regardless of the number I'm putting in

[screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/tOWMj8C.png)

Comment: if possible please do share a sample sheet for us to check it out bcoz most likely the issue is with the data within that cell / formatting done for that cell and all.